# How to let a button go to another day of an schedule (Like an Agenda App)

Tags: android

I am making some Buttons which perform an action corresponding to the day wired to the Button.
For instance, when you press 'Monday' it performs the action for `day=0`.

The following code doesn't work:

```
        buttonma = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonma);
        buttonma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                day = 0;
            }
        });
        buttondi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttondi);
        buttondi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                day = 1;

            }
        });
        buttonwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonwo);
        buttonwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                day = 2;

            }
        });
        buttondo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttondo);
        buttondo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                day = 3;

            }
        });
        buttonvr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonvr);
        buttonvr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                day = 4;

            }
        });
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.
You are changing the variable day , this will not change anything in the user interface.
What do you want to trigger on click exactly?

Comment: yes i need to let the user go to another day, the api looks like this for the days,
day": 0, "times": "08:55 - 09:40", "teacher": "Jng",

Comment: And i want if the user clicks on teusday it goes to  "day": 1, "times": "08:55 - 09:40", "teacher": "Dyk",